# Как найти заголовок на странице которую обрабатывает jquery а так же ссылки на ней

Tags: html, jquery, парсер

пользуюсь таким кодом.

```html
(function($){
function ajaxStart(){
  $('#progress').show();
}
function ajaxStop(){
  $('#progress').hide();
}
function parserGo(){
  ajaxStart();
  var b = $.ajax('http://www.tinko.ru/p-249287.html');
  b.done(function (d) {
    analysisSite(d);
    ajaxStop();
  });
  b.fail(function (e, g, f) {
    alert('Epic Fail');
    ajaxStop();
  })
}
function analysisSite(data){

var res1 = '';
var htmle = $(data).html('');
 $(htmle).find('title').each(function(){
 if(res1==''){
  res1=$(this).text();
  console.log(res1);
 }
}) 


}
$(function(){
  $('#progress').hide();
  $('#starter').click(parserGo);
});
})(jQuery);
```

сама суть

```html
var res1 = '';
var htmle = $(data).html('');
 $(htmle).find('title').each(function(){
 if(res1==''){
  res1=$(this).text();
  console.log(res1);
 }
})
```

не выходит получить название страницы.

Comment: Возвращает ли `data` что-то? Зачем `$(data).html('')` ?

Comment: если написать вместо console.log(res1); console.log(htmle); то в консоли будет список всех элементов страницы.

Comment: оха, в варабл data не понятные элементы. вот в варбл b есть текст всего html. но мне все равно не удается вытащить ничего от туда.

Answer (score 0):

Из того, что я понял: title - это не просто html-тэг, это свойство документа. Т.к. у вас нет никакого документа в рамках полученного html, то и title нет. Вывод - надо делать документ. Берем код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052012/1430631):

```js
function createDocument(html) {
  var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
  doc.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
  return doc;
}

...

function analysisSite(data) {

  var res1 = '';
  var htmle = $(data).html('');
  var doc = createDocument(data);
  $(doc).find('title').each(function() {
    if (res1 == '') {
      res1 = $(this).text();
      console.log(res1);
    }
  })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример №1.

Найти в данных, возвращаемых $.get() (как в html-строке) заданную подстроку, например, `<title>some text</title>` (с помощью регулярного выражения):

```
... 

function parser() {
  $.get('http://www.tinko.ru/p-249287.html', function(data) {
    var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
    var title = matches ? matches[1] : 'Не определено';
    console.log(title);
  });
}
```

Пример №2.

Вышеуказанный поиск неудобен, если нужно искать много элементов, и работать с их аттрибутами. Поэтому, сначала можно поместить данные, которые возвращает $.get() в DOM, например, создав временную переменную с div. Тогда функция изменится примерно так:

```
...

function parser() {
  $.get('http://www.tinko.ru/p-249287.html', function(data) {
    // помещаем полученные данные в переменную
    var container = $('<div/>').html(data);

    // и работаем с ними стандартными методами jquery, как с элементами DOM
    container.find('a').each(function() {
      // this - каждый найденный элемент;
      // свойство href у каждого найденного элемента <a>
      console.log($(this).attr('href'));
      // или текст
      console.log($(this).text());
    }); 
  });
}
```

Если во втором примере заменить

```
container.find('a')
```

на

```
container.find('title')
```

, результат `console.log($(this).text());` будет почти аналогичен первому примеру

Comment: ДА!)) это то что нужно!) заголовок я получил!) Спасибо!) А ссылки я так же могу найти только за место title href нужно писать верно?

Comment: @Михаил, в комментарии писать неудобно, изменил ответ, посмотрите. В принципе, все довольно просто...

Comment: Хм, не пойму. Почему то не работает. Ошибки вываливаются. Их столько же сколько элементов помещено в массив (мне так кажется).Ну не одна ошибка я имею в виду.

Comment: Покажите, что за ошибки

Comment: первые три всегда есть. после идут ошибки связанные с функцией парсинга. 
1)resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   

2)Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    

3)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token     

4) Refused to load the script 'http://cdn.tinko.ru/js/prototype/prototype.js?_=1492431640313' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

таких ошибок похожих друг на друга десятка три еще.

Comment: и после всего этого

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: ошибка не в функции. Судя по всему, у Вас экстеншен некорректно написан...  Политика безопасности запрещает делать то, что Вы хотите. Возможно, поможет добавление строки `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"` в файл `manifest.json`

Comment: Понял, попробую с компьютера не включенного в корпоративную сеть.